# Join Table Query : Table is not mapped

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, jpa, spring-boot

I have 4 entities and one join Table and I want to make a query like this :

**Collaborator :**

```
@Entity
public class Collaborator implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,
                      CascadeType.DETACH,
                      CascadeType.REFRESH }, 
           fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "UserID", nullable = true)
private User user;

@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,
                      CascadeType.DETACH,
                      CascadeType.REFRESH }, 
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "TaskID", nullable = true)
private Task task;

...}
```

**User :**

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.DETACH,
            CascadeType.REFRESH },
fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable( 
    name = "users_roles", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")) 
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

OneToMany(mappedBy="user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Collaborator> collaborators = new HashSet<>(); 
...}
```

**Role :**

```
@Entity
public class Role implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
private String name;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<User> users; 
... }
```

**Task :**

```
@Entity
public class Task implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "task",  fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Collaborator> collaborators = new HashSet<>();
...}
```

**My Problem :**

Is I want to fetch Tasks by Role And I tried this query  :

```
@Query("select t from Task as t, Collaborator as c, Role as r, User as u, users_roles as ur "
        + "where c.user = u.id "
        + "and u.id = ur.user_id "
        + "and r.id = ur.role_id "
        + "and r.name = :role "
        + "and c.task = t.id "
        + "and t.done = :done ")
List<Task> getTasksByRoleAndState(@Param("role")String role, @Param("done") boolean done);
```

but I got an error :

```
users_roles is not mapped
```

Any suggestion is most welcome, Thank you

Comment: So you have no ENTITY called "users_roles" as the message says clearly enough. And ? In JPQL you use JOIN across RELATIONS. You don't post your classes so how can anyone suggest what JOINs to make? JPQL != SQL

Comment: My classes are not needed for this, plus I mentioned that I have 4 entities and 1 jointable(it's clear I have a manytomany relationship)  and I also mentioned the join table links role and user entities.

Comment: My one problem maybe is the question : how can I access a join table from JPQL

Comment: you use the RELATIONs of your entities. The join table holds NOTHING that is not in the entities and the relations of the entities. You still haven't posted the entities, showing the relation fields

Comment: Ok i've changed my post, if you could take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPQL is structured around relations, so just navigate along the relations to include whatever entities you want to put constraints on. So, something like

```
SELECT t FROM Task t JOIN t.collaborators c JOIN c.user u JOIN u.roles r
WHERE r.name = :role AND t.done = :done
```

Consequently you don't reference any "join table", which is simply a persistence construction and irrelevant to querying.